# Find the maximum weight node in a tree if each node is the sum of the weights all the nodes under it.

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

For exa, this is the tree.

```
            10
     12           -1
  5       1     1     -2
2   3  10   -9
```

How to find the node with maximum value?

Comment: Is this the entire problem? If it is, there is no reason why you can't just check each node, since just reading the tree is already an `O(n)` operation. Maybe you have multiple queries / updates?

Answer (score 1):

Given the problem as stated, you need to traverse the entire tree. See proof below.

Traversing the entire tree should be a fairly trivial process.

**Proof that we need to traverse the entire tree:**

Assume we're able to identify which side of a tree the maximum is on without traversing the entire tree.

Given any tree with the maximum node on the left. Call this maximum `x`.

Pick one of the leaf nodes on the right. Add 2 children to it: `x+1` and `-x-1`.

Since `x+1-x-1 = 0`, adding these won't change the sum at the leaf we added it to, thus nor the sums at any other nodes in the tree.

Since this can be added to any leaf in the tree, and it doesn't affect the sums, we'd need to traverse the entire tree to find out if this occurs anywhere.

Thus our assumption that we can identify which side of a tree the maximum is on without traversing the entire tree is incorrect.

Thus we need to traverse the entire tree.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you need to traverse the entire tree. If the values in the tree are not constrained (e.g. all non-negative, but in your example there are negative values), then the value in a node tells you nothing about the individual values below it.